# How to print Decimal object with specified precision

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two float values 1000.4 and 700.7

The result of `1000.4 - 700.7` returns me `299.69999999999993`. I did my research,Decimal would be a good option to do the calculation here `print(Decimal('1000.4') - Decimal('700.7'))` and it returns `299.7`

I have a question. what if I have a value `14.5` how can I print it as `14.50`?

I tried `getcontext().prec = 2` and it didn't help and would made the `print(Decimal('1000.4') - Decimal('700.7'))` returns `3.0E+2` which isn't what I want.

Comment: `print("{:.2f}".format(14.5))` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use f-strings to custom the leading zeros/limit the precision.

```
n=14.5
print(f"{n:.2f}")
```

Here, it would print only the first two decimals. (14.50).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with formatting for both floats and Decimal.

```
In [1]: print("{:.2f}".format(1.234))
1.23

In [2]: from decimal import Decimal

In [3]: print("{:.2f}".format(Decimal(1.234)))
1.23
```